# How to use web api sonarcloud

Tags: json, python-2.7, sonarqube, sonarcloud

Recently I started using sonarcloud and I was asked for a university project to extract the technical debt of a project. I'm trying to use the web API exposed by sonarcloud but with little success. This is the python code I wrote

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get ('https://sonarcloud.io/component_measures?id=Huginn87_jabref/api/metrics/component?component=&metricKeys=sqale_index',auth= (' usr ',' pwd '))

code = r.status_code

print "Status code:", code

print r.json ()
```

and this is the result I get

```
Status code: 200

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print r.json ()

  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads (self.text, ** kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode (s)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode (s, idx = _w (s, 0) .end ())

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, ​​in raw_decode
    raise ValueError ("No JSON object could be decoded")

ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

According to the documentation, you should give me a json format, but it does not. Would anyone be kind enough to tell me where I'm wrong, please? Many thanks in advance. Greetings.

Comment: Well, print `r.text` instead and see it's not JSON

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately I have already tried and the result is this:

<! DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
...

With, what I think is the structure of the page in html. While I would expect to receive the class names and the relative technical debt :-( I have been beating my head for several days ...

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like it is trying to take you to a login page

Comment: Besides, that, your URL seems wrong. You can't have a `/` path following a query parameter, so `https://sonarcloud.io/component_measures/api/metrics/component??id=Huginn87_jabref&component=&metricKeys=sqale_index` looks better to me, or even just `https://sonarcloud.io/api`... But I don't know SonarCloud, so would need to see the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I report below the solution in case it served someone else. It is not possible to extract the metric with a python script neither with wget nor with curl, but you have to put the url in the address bar

https://sonarcloud.io/api/measures/component_tree?component=keyJabref4.2&metricKeys=sqale_index&ps=100&p=1

Changing the parameters
component -> the key to your project
metricKeys -> the metric you want to take
ps -> indicates the page size and therefore the number of elements that, at most, can be equal to 500 (from 0 to 499)
p -> indicates the page (Eg for projects of 1500 classes, you must first save the values with p = 1, then with p = 2 and then with p = 3)

I thank the people who tried to help me, even your suggestions have been helpful. I hope he can help you. Greetings

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution says that it is not possible to collect the metrics using `curl` or a Python script. First, I thought that the Sonarcloud API requires a certain set of headers to be set, but that is not the case.

In the following for completens, an example of accessing the Sonarcloud API via curl and Python with the example from above.

```sh
curl "https://sonarcloud.io/api/measures/component_tree?component=keyJabref4.2&metricKeys=sqale_index&ps=100&p=1"
```

Note the quotes around the URL, which I would guess were forgotten earlier.

Or similarly in Python with the `requests` module:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://sonarcloud.io/api/measures/component_tree'
query = {'component': 'keyJabref4.2', 'metricKeys': 'sqale_index', 'ps': 100, 'p': 1}
r = requests.get(url, params=query)
metrics_dict = r.json()
```

In both cases the API returns an HTTP status code 200 and the results are the same as when accessed through a browser.

As I stumbled over this question when searching for an example on how to use the Sonarcloud API, its documentation is here: https://sonarcloud.io/web_api